# Jquery- grabbing an image's alt tag content and adding as text (getting duplications)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a little script that takes an image's alt tag an adds it as text as such:

```
 $(".field-item a img").each(function(i, ele) {
          $(".field-item").append("<span>"+$(ele).attr("alt")+"</span>");
      });​
```

The issue I am having is I am getting duplication where every alt tag is added to every image as text. So for "`image-1`", `image-1` and `image-2` get added as text where I only want the corresponding alt tag added as text.

I tired using `.closest()` e.g.

```
$(".field-item").closest().append("<span>"+$(ele).attr("alt")+"</span>");
```

... but that did not seem to do the trick. I have fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/6pAZE/4/

Comment: Here's how I'd solve it, although there are several solutions: http://jsfiddle.net/6pAZE/9/. Also, "alt tag" :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `closest()` method, currently you are selecting all the elements with class of `field-item` in each iteration, try the following:

```
 $(".field-item a img").each(function(i, ele) {
     var alt = this.alt;
     $(this).closest(".field-item").append("<span>"+alt+"</span>");
     // or $(this).after("<span>"+alt+"</span>");
 });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pAZE/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to go up to the `.closest('.field-item')` then append your text.

http://jsfiddle.net/6pAZE/6/